# Copying and Pasting Arabic Text to Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, text, copy, copy-paste, arabic

I am copying Arabic Text along with HTML to a Wordpress (Raw HTML) form. When I copy over, the characters get jumbled up. Can anyone provide a solution to overcome this?

Comment: screenshot please. it happens if pasting Arabic text in Left-to-Right textarea or input. if that's the case you need to set element direction to rtl.

Answer (score 0):

Try Qtranalste plugin in which you can get option for create multilingual word press site.Where after enable Arabic language you can add separate Arabic text along with HTML to word press text editor and display same at front end as well.

```
https://wordpress.org/plugins/qtranslate/
```